# Lollipop plot in R with Ridge Regression coefficients

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, multicollinearity, ridge-regression

I have the following dataset, in which I want to understand the influence of four explanatory variables (`X1`, `X2`, `X3` and `X4`) on the response variable `Y`:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Y = c("28,1", "27,3", "25,9", "27,2", "30,6", 
"27,6", "28,4", "26,6", "28,1", "30,1", "26,3", "28,4", "26,1", 
"24,6", "26,9", "26,3", "26,7", "26,3", "28,1", "28,2"), X1 = c("27,8", 
"27,7", "26,6", "26,8", "30,7", "27,6", "25,4", "26,7", "26,7", 
"29,4", "25,1", "26,6", "25,2", "24,1", "26,7", "24,9", "26,1", 
"25,5", "27,7", "27,6"), X2 = c("27,5", "27,1", "26,2", "24,8", 
"27,2", "26,3", "23,9", "24,3", "24,1", "25,1", "24", "26,4", 
"24,8", "25,1", "24,2", "25,1", "24,5", "24,1", "25,9", "25,9"
), X3 = c("27,4", "27,4", "26,3", "25,8", "29,2", "27,1", "25", 
"24,8", "25,3", "27,7", "24,9", "25,7", "24,5", "24", "24", "24,4", 
"25,3", "25", "26,8", "27,1"), X4 = c(57L, 54L, 56L, 74L, 62L, 
62L, 67L, 68L, 67L, 63L, 63L, 59L, 70L, 70L, 69L, 67L, 65L, 69L, 
65L, 65L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

As there is high multicollinearity between the explanatory variables, I decided to use a Ridge Regression. How can I create a lollipop plot to demonstrate the direction (positive or negative) of each variable in the model, from the Ridge regression coefficients?

The chart I have in mind would look something like this: [image: Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you are looking for this solution:

```
library(glmnet)
library(ggplot2)
data <- structure(list(Y = c("28,1", "27,3", "25,9", "27,2", "30,6", 
                     "27,6", "28,4", "26,6", "28,1", "30,1", "26,3", "28,4", "26,1", 
                     "24,6", "26,9", "26,3", "26,7", "26,3", "28,1", "28,2"),
               X1 = c("27,8", "27,7", "26,6", "26,8", "30,7", "27,6", "25,4", "26,7", "26,7", 
                      "29,4", "25,1", "26,6", "25,2", "24,1", "26,7", "24,9", "26,1", 
                      "25,5", "27,7", "27,6"),
               X2 = c("27,5", "27,1", "26,2", "24,8", 
                      "27,2", "26,3", "23,9", "24,3", "24,1", "25,1", "24", "26,4", 
                      "24,8", "25,1", "24,2", "25,1", "24,5", "24,1", "25,9", "25,9"),
               X3 = c("27,4", "27,4", "26,3", "25,8", "29,2", "27,1", "25", 
                      "24,8", "25,3", "27,7", "24,9", "25,7", "24,5", "24", "24", "24,4", 
                      "25,3", "25", "26,8", "27,1"),
               X4 = c(57L, 54L, 56L, 74L, 62L, 
                      62L, 67L, 68L, 67L, 63L, 63L, 59L, 70L, 70L, 69L, 67L, 65L, 69L, 
                      65L, 65L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

#I assume your data is numeric, no strings-columns
data$Y <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".", data$Y))
data$X1 <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".", data$X1))
data$X2 <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".", data$X2))
data$X3 <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".", data$X3))

#Perform the ridge regression, you probably would like to add a parameter tuning step using cross validation
fit <- glmnet(x = data[,c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")],
              y =  data$Y,
              alpha = 0,
              lambda  = 1)

#Extract data to plot
plot_data <- data.frame(h = names(fit$beta[,1]), v = fit$beta[,1])

# Plot
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=h, y=v)) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=h, xend=h, y=0, yend=v), color="grey") +
  geom_point( color="orange", size=4) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-2),
    axis.title.y = element_text(angle=90, vjust=3)
  ) +
  xlab("Explanatory variable") +
  ylab("Regression coefficient")
```

Which would give you the following plot:

[image: Example plot]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly! =)